# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" : Minkowski inequality proof detail

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I do not understand the reason for the equality highlighted:

[image]

In my mind it is simply a case of the triangle inequality $|f+g| \le {|f|}+{|g|}$ , so should that not be an inequality ?

I ask because I see the same equality in Jacod's "Probability Essentials" proof of the same result, which makes me thing I am obviously wrong:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a misprint.

Comment: ok thank you. Still - the same misprint in 2 different books!

Comment: Are they independent misprints? Well they are probability books!